# Did followers of all Astika schools perform Vedic rituals?

Tags: philosophy, moksha, vedic-rituals, shad-darshana, pramana

While all the Astika schools of thought accept Vedas as one of pramana. Only **Mimansa** consider performing **Vedic rituals** as way to attain **Moksha**.
So, did followers of other schools like **Nyaya, Samkhya, Visheshika, Yoga** did not perform Vedic rituals like Yagna, Sandhyavandane, etc?

Also, most Hindus follow the Vedanta school of thought today and also perform Vedic rituals, when that isn't the described way to attain Moksha. Why is it so?

Comment: Apart from attaining Moksha, we all follow specific way to live and perform in Samsara and that's why we practice Rituals. Is your question about attaining Moksha only by means of performing rituals?

Comment: When all the astika schools differ on critical philosophical concepts of Atma, Brahman, universe and Moksha. Did they remain same in performing daily and traditional rituals? Or did the schools had difference in opinion regarding Vedic rituals also?